# Unable to install package "System" in Spyder

Tags: python, package, system, spyder

I have been able to install a few other packages with ease, however "System" is giving me trouble.

Below is my code: -

```
pip install System
import System
```

and here is the error: -

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement System (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for System
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know [there is no module called `System` in PiPy](https://pypi.org/search/?q=System), which is the module repository used by `pip`.

I think you are looking to use [the `sys` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), which is part of the core Python libraries, and do not need installing (comes already installed with python).

You can use it importing it directly without the need of installing it through pip:

```python
import sys
sys.copyright
```